# A matrix norm inequality II

Tags: inequalities, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the spectral norm, i.e., largest singular value.  The condition number of an invertible complex matrix $X$ is defined as $\kappa(X):=\|X\|\|X^{-1}\|$.

I am able to prove

**Proposition** Let $A, B$ be $n\times n$ positive definite matrices.  If $X$ is an $n\times n$  invertible matrix such that $AXB$ is Hermitian, then \begin{eqnarray*}
  \|X^{-1}AXB\|\le \kappa(X) \|AB\|. 
 \end{eqnarray*}

In particular, if moreover $X$ in the above proposition is unitary, then  $\|X^{-1}AXB\|\le \|AB\|$.

I wonder if  $\kappa(X)$ in the above proposition can always be replaced with $1$.

Comment: Very  interesting  proposition:  I  am  thinking  to  a proof, in  particular the case that  X is  unitary. Did  you  wrote  your  proof  some where(arxive, or  some  thing  like this?)I  am  thinking  for  possible  motivation  for  consideration of the  assumption $AXB$  is  hermitian?I  am thinking  for  some  geometric  interpretation for the proposition in the unitary  case. I  am  thinking  also  to the sharpnest  of  $\kappa (X)$ in your  inequality.  Very great post!

Comment: Does  your  argument  work  in  arbitrary  C*  algebra?

Comment: Are there there matrices  $A,B,X$ with  $A, B$ are positive  and  X  is  unitary such that $AXB$ is  Hermitian but  $AB \neq BA$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi sure, for example you can find a unitary matrix $X$ such that $AXB$ is equal to the geometric mean of $A^2$ and $B^2$, usually denoted by $A^2\sharp B^2$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I emailed you a proof of the proposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the  norm of  the left  side  can  be very  large.

For  example $\left\| X^{-1}AXB \right\| $  is  an  unbounded  function in $(x,y)$  where  $A,X,B$ are the  following  matrices:

Put $A=B= \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&2 \end{pmatrix}$  and  $X^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} -x^3&y\\y&x \end{pmatrix}$

where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$.

In this  example  $A,B$  are  positive matrices and   $AXB$ is equal to its transpose so is  a  Hermitian matrix.

This  shows  that the  inequality $\left\| X^{-1}AXB  \right\| \leq \left\|   A  B \right\|     $  is  not  necessarily  true.  Because  the  left  side is  unbounded function in $(x,y)$ but  the  right side  is  a  constant  function.

The  left  side  is unbounded  because  of  the  following  argument:

Put  $C=X^{-1}AXB$  then $C_{21}=xy/x^{4}+y^2$. Then $|C_{21}|$  tends  to  $+\infty$  when $y=x^2$  and  $x \to 0$. So $\parallel  C \parallel_{\infty}  = Max |C_{ij}|$  goes  to  infinity.  But  the  later  norm is  equivalent  to the spectral  norm.

Comment: can you explain why $\parallel X^{-1}AXB \parallel$ is unbounded in your example?

Comment: In this example, the left hand side is definitely not unbounded.

Comment: @M.Lin  I explain the  reason in the  revised  version of the  answer.

Comment: @M.Lin  you are well come.